# What would be the best approach to upgrade docker from v1.13.1 to v19.03.11?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We use docker as a container runtime in kubernetes. Currently we are on K8s `v1.19.7` but still using older version of docker `v1.13.1`, somehow we didn't upgrade docker with kubernetes. Now I am in a kind of situation where I have to upgrade to docker-ce `v19.03.11`, which is listed as a dependency with K8s `v1.19.7`.

Can anyone help me and suggest a good approach for it? Can I directly upgrade to `v19.03.11` or follow a certain path?

Yes, I will be doing a POC first then implementing it in our actual env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/) states you should make sure no previous version of Docker are installed, before installing new one.
Since version `1.13.1` is very old by now (released 2017-02-08), upgrading it to newest version may not be straightforward.

Your best bet would be to install newest version of Docker from scratch.

Comment: Ok I can test this. On a running K8s cluster I will drain the node, stop kubelet and docker service and then remove the old docker and install a new docker v19.03.11. They have mentioned in the doc that removing old version will not delete images, containers and volumes. So I will give this a try.